# I need to convert this code to ES6, I'm very new on JS and I'm not sure how to

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I'm new on JS and not very familiar with the old version, I have this test that I need to convert into Es6. Does anyone could help me to understand how I can do this?

```
'use strict';
function Shape(id, x, y) {
 this.id = id;
 this.setLocation(x, y);
}
Shape.prototype.setLocation = function(x, y) {
 this.x = x;
 this.y = y;
};
Shape.prototype.getLocation = function() {
 return {
 x: this.x,
 y: this.y
 };
};
Shape.prototype.toString = function() {
 return 'Shape(' + this.id + ')';
};
function Circle(id, x, y, radius) {
 Shape.call(this, id, x, y);
 this.radius = radius;
}
Circle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);
Circle.prototype.constructor = Circle;
Circle.prototype.toString = function() {
 return 'Circle > ' + Shape.prototype.toString.call(this);
};
```

Comment: Start with `class Shape { ... }`, then move everything from the constructor function into the `constructor(...) { ... }`, and add the prototype methods as `setLocation(...) { ... }` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converted to [classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes):

```js
class Shape {
  constructor(id, x, y) {
    this.id = id;
    this.setLocation(x, y);
  }
  setLocation(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
  getLocation = () => ({
    x: this.x,
    y: this.y
  })

  toString() {
    return `Shape(${this.id})`;
  }
}

class Circle extends Shape {
  constructor(id, x, y, radius) {
    super(id, x, y)
    this.radius = radius;
  }
  toString() {
    return `Circle> ${super.toString()}`;
  }
}

let shape = new Shape('shape', 5, 5);
let circle = new Circle('circle', 6, 6, 6);


console.log("Shape()",
  shape.getLocation(),
  shape.toString()
);
console.log("Circle()",
  circle.getLocation(),
  circle.toString()
);
```

Hope this helps,